# EF-EOS M adapter+Canon 18-135mm IS Nano USM not focusing

Tags: canon

I've just got EF-EOS M adapter and Canon 18-135mm IS Nano USM to use with my M50 and focus is not working at all
In the menu at lens aberation correction all are on except Digital Lens Optimizer where is written: correction data not available
What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Check the gold electronic contacts on the camera body, the adapter (both sides), and on the lens to make sure everything is clean, unbroken, and unobstructed.

Also check how the adapter is seated on your camera, and how the lens is seated on the adapter. It's probably that not some of the  pins/contacts of the mounts are not touching, so electronic communication cannot be established between the lens and the camera body.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply; I'll do so

Comment: @Virgil, if this advice solves your issue, consider [accepting it](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Comments are more like footnotes than replies here on SE.